# Herband model for a forumla

Tags: logic, formal-languages

I need to find a Herband model for the formula
$Pc \land \forall x (\exists y  (Px \leftrightarrow \neg Py))$,
where $c$ is a constant and $P$ is a unary relation.
I've already read the theory but unfortunately don't understand how to proceed in practice. It would be nice if someone can help me with some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ref. to [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_first_order_logic).

1) Transform the formula in a set $s$ of [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) in [Conjunctive Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), removing the universal quantifiers and replacing existentially-quantified variables by [Skolem functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form):

> $S = \{ Pc, ¬Px \lor ¬Pf(x), Pf(x) \lor Px \}$.

2) Build the [Herbrand universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_universe) with *constant* and *function* symbols.

Having only the *constant* $c$ and the *skolem function* $f$, the H-universe will be:

> $U = \{ c, f(c), f(f(c)), \ldots \}$.

3) Build the [Herbrand base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure#Herbrand_base) for the set $S$ of clauses, i.e. the set of all *ground atoms* of the form $P(t)$ for the only *predicate* symbol occurring in $S$ using the closed terms in $U$:

> $H_b = \{ Pc, Pf(c), Pf(f(c)), \ldots \}$.

Finally:

4) build the [Herbrand interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_interpretation):

> every constant is interpreted as itself, and every function symbol is interpreted as the function that applies it. The interpretation also defines predicate symbols as denoting a subset of the relevant Herbrand base, effectively specifying which ground atoms are true in the interpretation. This allows the symbols in a set of clauses to be interpreted in a purely syntactic way, separated from any real instantiation.

In your example:

> $H_I= \{ Pc, ¬Pc \lor \lnot Pf(c), Pf(c) \lor Pc, \ldots \}$.

---

See:

- Chin-Liang Chang & Richard Char-Tung Lee, [Symbolic Logic and Mechanical Theorem Proving](https://books.google.it/books?id=oGriBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA45) (1973), *Ch.4* : **Herbrand's Theorem**, page 45-on.

---

---

You can compare it with a "minimal" model $\mathcal M$ with universe $\{ a , b \}$ such that:

> $c^{\mathcal M} = a$ and $P^{\mathcal M} = \{ a \}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this the correct Skolem normalform? $\forall x (Pc \land (Px \leftrightarrow \neg Pfx))$

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 - yes; a *skolem function* in place of an existentially quantified variable, with as many arguments as the number of universal quantifiers preceding it: in this case one.

Comment: Could You please check if I correctly solved this one: $\forall x (Px \lor \exists \neg Px)$? I have the Herband universe $\{a,f(a),f(f(a)),...\}$ ($a$ ist the constant) and the model $\{Pa \lor \neg Pf(a), Pf(a) \lor \neg Pf(f(a)),Pf(f(a)) \lor \neg Pf(f(f(a)),...\}$.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 - No. $∀x(Px ∨ ∃x¬Px)$ is equivalent to: $∀xPx ∨ ∃x¬Px$; thus, you do not need $f$. The result is: $Px ∨ ¬Pa$.